# Trouble with jquery scrollTop function

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to follow the DRY principle by changing a bunch of repeated functions, but I'm stuck here. I want to change this scroll to function that is repeated 4 times with different **classes** and **ids** to a more generic way (I'm using *jQuery*):

```
  $('.empresa').click(function(event){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#empresa").offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
  $('.nosotros').click(function(event){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#nosotros").offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
```

the classes are elements of a navigation within a ul which looks something like this.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index#nosotros" class="nosotros">Link to the anchor</a></li>
    <li><a href="index#empresa" class="empresa">Link to the anchor</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the scroll to tags are div elements with this tags.

```
<div class="some-random-class" id="empresa" name="empresa">
<div class="some-random-class" id="nosotros" name="nosotros">
```

I was using this new selector to grab the class of the list with the proper anchor but I'm having trouble with the scroll part of the function, I don't know to use/convert the class or name of the object extracted to an id so I can keep use it the same way I was doing before.

```
$('.nav li').children('a').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).attr('class') );
});
```

hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.nav > li > a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).prop('class')).offset().top
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use:

```
$('.fluidJump').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var offset = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:offset}, 500);
});
```

Add "fluidJump" class on hiperlink to go to that section with animation. (number value)

```
<a href="#sectionid">Go to section</a>
```